# SFTP Dual Factor Authentication

Tags: linux, ssh, perl, ksh, sftp

**My Issue**

I am trying to automate a file fetch from an external [SFTP] server. The server is using 2-factor authentication. First, it needs a public-private key pairing established [This has already been done], next, it asks for a password for login.

**My Constraints**

The server's settings are outside my control [Its a vendor system] and I would prefer not to install modules like expect or sshpass [company policy]. I can use PERL/KSH for automating the fetch, along with most applications that come pre-installed on RHL [CURL,WGET,etc].

Is there any way out of this?

Comment: I don't think so. You can probably code similar thing like expect or sshpass, but why? Two-factor authentication was made to increase security and storing both factors on the same place will boil back down to not-secure-at-all.

Comment: Change that weird policy.

Comment: @Jakuje : We need to automate the transfer, this is one among several files that we fetch, the rest of which are already automated [None of the rest require two-factor authentication].

Comment: @sebix : I wish I could, but this is a small change and the leadership would be none too happy installing modules just for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test if you can simply provide the password for the 2nd prompt via stdin.

If that doesn't work then you have little choice but to use an expect-type solution. Since you're allowed to use Perl, you should be allowed to use Perl modules

- https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect
- https://metacpan.org/pod/Expect::Simple